# Cannot find target 'build' for project 'mylib'

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

i'm getting this error when i try to build the project
**ng build mylib**
result :  **Cannot find target 'build' for project 'mylib'**

Comment: could you share the `angular.json` pls?

Answer (score -1):

```html
nx.json
{
  "npmScope": "backbase",
  "affected": {
    "defaultBase": "main"
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/angular",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  },
  "implicitDependencies": {
    "package.json": {
      "dependencies": "*",
      "devDependencies": "*"
    },
    ".eslintrc.json": "*"
  },
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "@nrwl/workspace/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": ["build", "lint", "test", "e2e"]
      }
    }
  },
  "targetDependencies": {
    "build": [
      {
        "target": "build",
        "projects": "dependencies"
      }
    ]
  },
  "generators": {
    "@nrwl/angular:application": {
      "style": "scss",
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "karma",
      "e2eTestRunner": "cypress",
      "prefix": "bb",
      "strict": false
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:library": {
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "karma",
      "prefix": "bb",
      "strict": false
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "retail-usa"
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7BMe.png.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).